# how to logout in an app that is using Google sign-in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, vuejs3, google-signin

I am using Javascript (Vue app) and using [login with google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview)

When logging out, we would like to revoke the token, besides deleting it from the frontend side of the app.

We found the option to revoke the id token [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/revoke) but it seems like this is revoking the entire connection between the application to the user account including data access.

What is the proper way to log out a user after a Google sign-in, without breaking the entire connection between the user and the app?